# Why is GIS WHERE clause costing me so much?

Tags: postgresql-performance, postgis, spatial

I've got this view that has problems with performance, at the moment I use st_intersects to filter this data, something that's a necessary part of the functionality, I need to be able to see that a field is within a teams available work area.

TLDR: The view is as of now working and not performing badly, what I am worried about is the future as this is done with a very limited set of test data and the increased cost that the GIS WHERE clause seems to be adding seems weirdly huge, is there anyway to improve this? GIST indexes have been implemented.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    bookings.id AS booking_id,
    bookings.status,
    bookings.start_date,
    bookings.end_date,
    services.id AS service_id,
    bookings.user_id,
    customer.id AS team_id,
    teams.id AS contractor_team_id,
    bookings.created_at,
    bookings.updated_at,
    bookings.deleted_at
FROM
    bookings
    LEFT JOIN teams customer ON bookings.team_id = customer.id
    LEFT JOIN services ON bookings.service_id = services.id
    LEFT JOIN bookings_fields_fields ON bookings.id = bookings_fields_fields.booking_id
    LEFT JOIN fields ON bookings_fields_fields.field_id = fields.id,
    teams
    LEFT JOIN availabilities ON teams.id = availabilities.team_id
    LEFT JOIN vats ON teams.vat = vats.id
WHERE
    bookings.service_id = availabilities.service_id
    AND availabilities.is_available = TRUE
    AND vats.is_valid = TRUE
    AND customer.id <> teams.id
    AND st_intersects(fields.geo_polygon, teams.work_area) = TRUE;
```

With the st_intersects I get this query plan:

```
HashAggregate  (cost=873.08..937.51 rows=6443 width=128) (actual time=33.497..33.880 rows=1911 loops=1)
  Group Key: bookings.id, bookings.status, bookings.start_date, bookings.end_date, services.id, bookings.user_id, customer.id, teams.id, bookings.created_at, bookings.updated_at, bookings.deleted_at
  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 745kB
  ->  Hash Join  (cost=311.99..695.90 rows=6443 width=128) (actual time=2.496..30.316 rows=8082 loops=1)
        Hash Cond: (bookings_fields_fields.field_id = fields.id)
        Join Filter: st_intersects(fields.geo_polygon, teams.work_area)
        Rows Removed by Join Filter: 74
        ->  Hash Join  (cost=147.12..233.89 rows=8386 width=712) (actual time=1.912..3.479 rows=8156 loops=1)
              Hash Cond: (bookings_fields_fields.booking_id = bookings.id)
              ->  Seq Scan on bookings_fields_fields  (cost=0.00..12.10 rows=610 width=32) (actual time=0.007..0.061 rows=595 loops=1)
              ->  Hash  (cost=128.05..128.05 rows=1526 width=696) (actual time=1.902..1.905 rows=1931 loops=1)
                    Buckets: 2048  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1389kB
                    ->  Hash Join  (cost=95.26..128.05 rows=1526 width=696) (actual time=0.432..1.375 rows=1931 loops=1)
                          Hash Cond: (teams.vat = vats.id)
                          ->  Hash Join  (cost=93.58..122.02 rows=1526 width=712) (actual time=0.418..1.064 rows=1946 loops=1)
                                Hash Cond: (availabilities.team_id = teams.id)
                                Join Filter: (customer.id <> teams.id)
                                Rows Removed by Join Filter: 100
                                ->  Hash Join  (cost=87.50..111.42 rows=1558 width=128) (actual time=0.391..0.682 rows=2046 loops=1)
                                      Hash Cond: (bookings.service_id = availabilities.service_id)
                                      ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=10.49..15.21 rows=111 width=128) (actual time=0.036..0.101 rows=142 loops=1)
                                            Hash Cond: (bookings.service_id = services.id)
                                            ->  Hash Join  (cost=6.08..10.50 rows=111 width=112) (actual time=0.016..0.057 rows=142 loops=1)
                                                  Hash Cond: (bookings.team_id = customer.id)
                                                  ->  Seq Scan on bookings  (cost=0.00..4.11 rows=111 width=112) (actual time=0.002..0.013 rows=142 loops=1)
                                                  ->  Hash  (cost=5.48..5.48 rows=48 width=16) (actual time=0.010..0.010 rows=52 loops=1)
                                                        Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 11kB
                                                        ->  Seq Scan on teams customer  (cost=0.00..5.48 rows=48 width=16) (actual time=0.001..0.005 rows=52 loops=1)
                                            ->  Hash  (cost=3.07..3.07 rows=107 width=16) (actual time=0.019..0.019 rows=107 loops=1)
                                                  Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 14kB
                                                  ->  Seq Scan on services  (cost=0.00..3.07 rows=107 width=16) (actual time=0.002..0.010 rows=107 loops=1)
                                      ->  Hash  (cost=57.74..57.74 rows=1542 width=32) (actual time=0.352..0.352 rows=1549 loops=1)
                                            Buckets: 2048  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 113kB
                                            ->  Seq Scan on availabilities  (cost=0.00..57.74 rows=1542 width=32) (actual time=0.004..0.196 rows=1549 loops=1)
                                                  Filter: is_available
                                                  Rows Removed by Filter: 25
                                ->  Hash  (cost=5.48..5.48 rows=48 width=600) (actual time=0.026..0.026 rows=52 loops=1)
                                      Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 28kB
                                      ->  Seq Scan on teams  (cost=0.00..5.48 rows=48 width=600) (actual time=0.003..0.015 rows=52 loops=1)
                          ->  Hash  (cost=1.30..1.30 rows=30 width=16) (actual time=0.011..0.012 rows=30 loops=1)
                                Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 10kB
                                ->  Seq Scan on vats  (cost=0.00..1.30 rows=30 width=16) (actual time=0.004..0.007 rows=30 loops=1)
                                      Filter: is_valid
        ->  Hash  (cost=157.72..157.72 rows=572 width=1590) (actual time=0.493..0.493 rows=572 loops=1)
              Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 925kB
              ->  Seq Scan on fields  (cost=0.00..157.72 rows=572 width=1590) (actual time=0.002..0.194 rows=572 loops=1)
Planning Time: 4.105 ms
Execution Time: 34.012 ms
```

But if I remove the st_intersects WHERE clause I get this:

```
HashAggregate  (cost=464.51..548.37 rows=8386 width=128) (actual time=5.340..5.704 rows=1931 loops=1)
  Group Key: bookings.id, bookings.status, bookings.start_date, bookings.end_date, services.id, bookings.user_id, customer.id, teams.id, bookings.created_at, bookings.updated_at, bookings.deleted_at
  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1193kB
  ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=147.12..233.89 rows=8386 width=128) (actual time=1.723..2.913 rows=8156 loops=1)
        Hash Cond: (bookings_fields_fields.booking_id = bookings.id)
        ->  Seq Scan on bookings_fields_fields  (cost=0.00..12.10 rows=610 width=32) (actual time=0.004..0.042 rows=595 loops=1)
        ->  Hash  (cost=128.05..128.05 rows=1526 width=128) (actual time=1.715..1.717 rows=1931 loops=1)
              Buckets: 2048  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 317kB
              ->  Hash Join  (cost=95.26..128.05 rows=1526 width=128) (actual time=0.435..1.389 rows=1931 loops=1)
                    Hash Cond: (teams.vat = vats.id)
                    ->  Hash Join  (cost=93.58..122.02 rows=1526 width=144) (actual time=0.420..1.075 rows=1946 loops=1)
                          Hash Cond: (availabilities.team_id = teams.id)
                          Join Filter: (customer.id <> teams.id)
                          Rows Removed by Join Filter: 100
                          ->  Hash Join  (cost=87.50..111.42 rows=1558 width=128) (actual time=0.397..0.682 rows=2046 loops=1)
                                Hash Cond: (bookings.service_id = availabilities.service_id)
                                ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=10.49..15.21 rows=111 width=128) (actual time=0.037..0.102 rows=142 loops=1)
                                      Hash Cond: (bookings.service_id = services.id)
                                      ->  Hash Join  (cost=6.08..10.50 rows=111 width=112) (actual time=0.016..0.056 rows=142 loops=1)
                                            Hash Cond: (bookings.team_id = customer.id)
                                            ->  Seq Scan on bookings  (cost=0.00..4.11 rows=111 width=112) (actual time=0.002..0.012 rows=142 loops=1)
                                            ->  Hash  (cost=5.48..5.48 rows=48 width=16) (actual time=0.010..0.010 rows=52 loops=1)
                                                  Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 11kB
                                                  ->  Seq Scan on teams customer  (cost=0.00..5.48 rows=48 width=16) (actual time=0.001..0.005 rows=52 loops=1)
                                      ->  Hash  (cost=3.07..3.07 rows=107 width=16) (actual time=0.020..0.020 rows=107 loops=1)
                                            Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 14kB
                                            ->  Seq Scan on services  (cost=0.00..3.07 rows=107 width=16) (actual time=0.002..0.011 rows=107 loops=1)
                                ->  Hash  (cost=57.74..57.74 rows=1542 width=32) (actual time=0.358..0.358 rows=1549 loops=1)
                                      Buckets: 2048  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 113kB
                                      ->  Seq Scan on availabilities  (cost=0.00..57.74 rows=1542 width=32) (actual time=0.003..0.206 rows=1549 loops=1)
                                            Filter: is_available
                                            Rows Removed by Filter: 25
                          ->  Hash  (cost=5.48..5.48 rows=48 width=32) (actual time=0.020..0.020 rows=52 loops=1)
                                Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 11kB
                                ->  Seq Scan on teams  (cost=0.00..5.48 rows=48 width=32) (actual time=0.002..0.013 rows=52 loops=1)
                    ->  Hash  (cost=1.30..1.30 rows=30 width=16) (actual time=0.014..0.014 rows=30 loops=1)
                          Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 10kB
                          ->  Seq Scan on vats  (cost=0.00..1.30 rows=30 width=16) (actual time=0.006..0.009 rows=30 loops=1)
                                Filter: is_valid
Planning Time: 1.693 ms
Execution Time: 5.842 ms
```

In other words i go from a planning time of 4.188ms and an execution time of 34.422ms to a planning time of 1.553ms and an execution time of 5.790ms by removing the st_intersects where clause.

I've tried improving the performance by using other other geo spacial where clauses like st_dwithin but that came with even worse performance. I've double checked my indexes as well and can't really figure out what I am doing wrong.

Following are pictures of the teams table and the fields table that are used in the gis query.

The fields table:[image: A picture showing the fields tables structure]the geo_polygon column is a geo_polygon describing the fields layout.

The teams table:[image] the  work_area is a geo_polygon describing the geographical area a team is willing to work within

I am a bit stumped by the behavior and would love any possible feedback, right now the numbers are low but we're still in a beta phase with very few users, if nothing else I would greatly appreciate any pointers towards source material that I could read to gain greater understanding of the performance impact of using a gis function in a query like this.

Thanks in advance for any advice or help!

Comment: Formatted text please, no images. 34 milliseconds doesn't seem very slow to me.

Comment: Please do not post text information as (barely readable) screen shots. Sharing the plan as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and making sure to preserve the indention of the plan is not that hard. **[Edit]** your question, paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan. You can also share the plan through https://explain.depesz.com/

Comment: I can't read your pictures but do you have a spatial index on the geometry columns?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry about the barely readable screenshots, I've got a very big screen so I did not think about how they would translate to smaller screensizes. Will recify post with formatted text!

Comment: Three items: 1) Your explain plans appear to be corrupted (mixed indentation and the last 2 lines are at the beginning somehow). Make sure they are getting copied accurately. 2) The query is running ST_Intersects() on 8156 rows; it's just going to take a while, especially if the geometries are large. Indexes don't help a join filter. Consider applying more filtering to shrink the search set. 3) The teams table is joined twice, the second time as a cross join with the comma operator. Is that what you want?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @dwhitemv, I believe I managed to fix the query plans! :) 

The double join on the teams table is intentional, it's because I am basically sharing data between groups(teams), I let the contractor retrieve this view if their team id is left as a contractor_team_id and they will of course be interested in who has made the order, which is why the customer_team is there as well.

Anyhow, I will look into trying to limit the number of rows the query needs to run against. :)

Comment: Mixing comma joins and JOIN stanzas can have surprising effects. I suggest rewriting the second teams join to use modern syntax like the rest.